# Wordpress Product Attribute custom permalink

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change product attribute base url permalink.

For example : www.mystore.com/color/blue 
and my desired url is : www.mystore.com/blue

Please help..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the option "Enable Archives?" to enable the attribute to be viewable on the front end as an archive page. Then to change the URL you can edit the slug.

The final URL is as the following: 
www.mystore.com/{attribute_slug}/{term_slug}

Thanks

Comment: I want to remove {attribute_slug}, is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure about that when you enable the archive to a  tag, it will have a unique URL and the unique part is the {attribut_slug} so I think it's not possible. you can make the slug a single character like '-' or '1'. Give it a try and let me know.